# Lumen : How to display the image on a public folder?

Tags: php, image, laravel, lumen

I want to display the image that stored in public folder on Lumen project.
But I got 404 not found when try to display it in browser.

I already create the asset url helper:

```
if (!function_exists('urlGenerator')) {
    /**
     * @return \Laravel\Lumen\Routing\UrlGenerator
     */
    function urlGenerator() {
        return new \Laravel\Lumen\Routing\UrlGenerator(app());
    }
}

if (!function_exists('asset')) {
    /**
     * @param $path
     * @param bool $secured
     *
     * @return string
     */
    function asset($path, $secured = false) {
        return urlGenerator()->asset($path, $secured);
    }
}
```

and this is how I call the image URL :

```
asset('public/uploads/images/product/') . $product->image
```

why lumen referring to route when I try to call image in public folder ?

Comment: Are you sure you need `public` in `asset('public/uploads/images/product/') . $product->image`?

Comment: oh ok it's solved thanks

Comment: please could you share your code with me saving the image and get the url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like the below.

```
asset('uploads/images/product/' . $product->image)
```

or

```
asset('uploads/images/product/') . '/' . $product->image
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`asset()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-asset) URL helper already generates a path to your root folder (which is inside the `public` fodler) and so you don't need to include it.

Using:

```
asset('uploads/images/product/' . $product->image)
```

or

```
asset('uploads/images/product/') . $product->image
```

should work just fine for you.

Remember you can always look at the link that gets generated to see what your helper is generating - and tweak it as required.